# Displaying Multiple ImageViews iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, asynchronous, uiimageview

I have some kind of user input which will result in displaying 4 images at a time. The images are downloaded online asynchronously. My ViewController has a delegate method which will display the image when its ready as follows:

```
- (void)imageDidLoad:(UIImage *)image {

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, 192, 192)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    imageView.image = image;

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    xOffset = xOffset + 192;

    if (count != 0 && count % 4 == 0) {
        yOffset += 192;
        xOffset = 0;
    }

    count++;
}
```

I want to implement a next button, and each request will display four images at a time. In my `imageDidLoad`, when the second image has been loaded and is ready to be displayed, previous one will cause a memory leak.

What are alternatives to this? Should I just autorelease `UIImageViews`? Anything else I can do (better than autorelease)?

Thanks,

Comment: The only better way than autorelease is release, surely? Why aren't you doing this currently?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new UIImageView each time an image is loaded, I'd make the 4 UIImageViews properties of the controller.  Then, I'd modify the image property of the appropriate UIImageView once the picture is downloaded.  You'd release the properties in - (void)dealloc as usual.

Comment: Yes but in this case, I would only be able to display 4 images at a time. I want to display 4 at at a time, but when I click on 'next', another 4 will display and the old ones stay. That way, I can't just make 4 and keep reusing - correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should release your imageView after you've added it as a subview. That will fix your leak.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, but you really should reuse the imageView instead of create each time new one.

```
- (void)imageDidLoad:(UIImage *)image {

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, 192, 192)];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
imageView.image = image;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

xOffset = xOffset + 192;

if (count != 0 && count % 4 == 0) {
    yOffset += 192;
    xOffset = 0;
}

count++;
```

}

Comment: Oh so my view will retain the image view? Also, how would I reuse the image views?